# Git use a code from another branch

Tags: git, branch

I've created a branch **BranchA** from **develop**. On this branch, I've made some feature AND I've fixed an issue. Then I've created a PR for the original repo, because I'm just a contributor.
The PR is not yet accepted because we are still working on it.

Now, I'm working on a new feature, so I've created a branch from **develop** too : **BranchB**.
But I cannot continue my development because I don't have the fix of the issue which I've fixed on the **BranchA**.

So I would like to fix the same issue in the new branch (**BranchB**). But I think it's not the best idea to do the same thing twice.
What's the best practice and how can I do for getting the code from **BranchA** into **BranchB**.

Just for reminder, the **BranchA** is still running under development.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I think a rebase could work.

checkout BranchB and rebase your BranchB on BranchA with:

```
git rebase BranchA
```

and you will have BranchA's history on your BranchB.

Answer (score 1):

[cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) those few commits that fixes the issue:

```
git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 etc…
```

If you need all commits between commit1 and commit2:

```
git cherry-pick commit1~..commit2
```

Note the tilde!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to partial checkout the file containing the fix while having **BranchB** checked-out:

```
git checkout <revision> -- path/of/file/containing/fix
```

revision here is a commitish, meaning that it has to point to a commit. So executing:

```
git checkout BranchA -- path/of/file/containing/fix
```

would checkout the state of path/of/file/containing/fix based on **BranchA**'s state onto your current working tree. The file will be un-staged after the partial checkout and it is up to you what do with it from there on.

Keep in mind that if you have any un-staged changes to the file containing fix before the partial checkout they will get overwritten. So depending on what you are comfortable with, either stage and commit, just stage, or stash the changes before performing the partial checkout.

Answer (score 0):

just checkout to branchA copy the code into a separate folder outside the repo, then checkout back to to branchB then plug in the code you need or just `git checkout -b branchB` from branchA but you would be creating a possible throw away codebase in case your code from branchA is rejected.